# Reference Request for Quantum Hall Effect

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

Are there are any good references on the Quantum Hall Effect written for mathematicians? It would be best if it was self-contained, i.e., missing proofs would be OK if they were standard in graduate-level functional analysis, measure theory, etc.

Comment: A general comment : Mathematics can only describe physical phenomens quantitative. It cannot replace the understanding of a physical process nor can it prove physical laws. Unfortunately, modern physics , in particular cosmology , ignores this important fact, with sad consequences.

Comment: @Peter That’s true. However, I personally find it easier to understand the physical motivation of a mathematical formulation after I somewhat understand the formulation, even though that’s the wrong order to do research.

Comment: There is also the observed fractional quantum Hall effect to consider. I'm not entirely sure that there exists a single mathematical model, encompassing all the experimentally observed fractional and integer quantum hall effects, that is also fully consistent with the existing tenets of quantum mechanics? I suspect this is still an active field of research for physicists.